# TLS1.3 transcript hash

Tags: hash, sha-256

From RFC8446:

*For concreteness, the transcript hash is always taken from the
following sequence of handshake messages, starting at the first
ClientHello and including only those messages that were sent:
ClientHello, HelloRetryRequest, ClientHello, ServerHello,
EncryptedExtensions, server CertificateRequest, server Certificate,
server CertificateVerify, server Finished, EndOfEarlyData, client
Certificate, client CertificateVerify, client Finished.*

Messaages starting with Encrypted Extensions and after are encrypted. When calculating the hash (ex. SHA256), it is done over the encrypted form as they arrived, of over the decrypted text ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you read the 4.1 completely?

Comment: Yes. Could you please be more specific ?

Comment: Aren't the first paragraph gives the answer to your question?

Comment: No, I don't see any connection to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The computation is done on the clear text. The reason being encryption and decryption of messages is done at the record level, not the handshake one. If the transcription-hash was computed based on the encrypted text then it would be trivial for an attacker in a mitm situation to determine it, inject its own messages and transmit the resulting hash inside the Finish handshake.

Comment: The comment about mitm attacks is quite inaccurate. The finish message doesn't simply send a hash but a MAC over the transcript hash. So a mitm can't do much unless the attacker also has knownledge of the session key.